# How do I connect a (concrete) push-switch / button to MIT app inventor

Tags: arduino

How do I connect a (concrete) push-switch / button to MIT app inventor or is there another way I can connect an actual button/switch (like the ones used in bread boards) to an app I am making. I know there is a way because there are so many videos doing the opposite (controlling Arduino with app). Thank you so much!

I am new to robotics and programming so I am not sure which hardware (bluetooth/arduino/rasberry pie/bread board) I should be using. Thank you

Comment: This question is awfully too broad. And Hardware recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: And why are you [reposting the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357723/how-do-i-connect-a-concrete-push-switch-button-to-an-app-i-am-developing) with a different tag?

Answer (score 0):

After briefly looking at the app inventor website, I see that it is basically an Android app IDE with some MIT library stuff baked in. When developing a MIT App Inventor app, the concrete buttons you mention would then be part of the android app you are developing (usually a touch screen button on your phone that shows up when you load the app).

If you wanted to leverage the App Inventor library and hook up a physical switch from some sort of embedded device, you might want a Client-Server sort of application. Or you could find some simple embedded device that support android.

This means you might hook up a push switch to some sort of embedded device, like the Esp32 or Esp8266 which is capable of bluetooth and wifi. The esp32 could then ask your android app some question based on a button push. The android app would respond with an answer or just display some data through the app.